# jquery jumps instead of scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason my page 'jumps' instead of smoothly scrolling after clicking an internal link in menu 2nd time.
I'm quite sure that has something to do with **scrolling.js** file, i'm a newbie in jQuery and probably messed something up. Since you've commented that it's working just fine let me explain it on example. I enter the page I can press "About" button in menu and it scrolls just fine, I can press the "Learn About Me" button and it works fine as well, go to top arrow on the side menu works too but if you scroll manually a bit and then try to press "About" in menu it doesn't scroll but jump even if you scroll back to top and press it the same way it worked after the page load.
 [the page itself](http://pawcza.github.io/).

**scrolling.js**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var height = $('section').height();
height = height * 0.2;
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= height) {
$('nav').css('background','rgba(0,0,0,0)');
$('nav').css('margin-left','0px');
$('.OTOCWEL').css('background','rgba(0,0,0,0)');
$('#powered').css('background','rgba(0,0,0,0)').addClass('fixerpowered');
$('.menu').addClass('menuslim');
$('.menu').removeClass('menu');
$('.menuslim').css('margin-left','0px').css('opacity','1');
$('#first').addClass('mega-octicon octicon-info').css('margin-left','0px');
$('#second').addClass('mega-octicon octicon-book');
$('#third').addClass('mega-octicon octicon-mail');
$('#fourth').addClass('mega-octicon octicon-diff-added');
$('.OTOCWEL').css('display','none');
$('.suwak').css('display','none');
$('.dzolero').css('display','block');
} else  {
$('nav').css('background','rgba(0,0,0,0.5)');
$('.menuslim').addClass('menu');
$('.menu').removeClass('menuslim').css('top','0px');
$('#first').html("<a>About</a>").css('margin-    left','15px').removeClass('mega-octicon octicon-info');
$('#first>a').attr('href','#about');
$('#second').html("<a>Projects</a>").removeClass('mega-octicon octicon-book');
$('#second>a').attr('href','#projects');
$('#third').html("<a>Contact</a>").removeClass('mega-octicon octicon-mail');
$('#third>a').attr('href','#contact');
$('#fourth').html("<a>Additional</a>").removeClass('mega-octicon octicon-diff-added');
$('#fourth>a').attr('href','#additional');
$('.OTOCWEL').css('display','initial');
$('.suwak').css('display','block');
$('#powered').removeClass('fixerpowered');
$('.dzolero').css('display','none');
}
});
```

**scroll.js**

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
}
```

});

Comment: I dont see any jumping.... Im using Chrome!

Comment: I too don't see any jumping. Chrome 48!

Comment: Strange, i'm using Chrome as well. Do you see the jumping if you scroll page manually a bit and then press the "About" button ?

Comment: @pawcza kudos on the ideas for your personal site, keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your JQuery selector `$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')` is the source of the problem.

When it comes to your anchor links (the ones that do not redirect to a new page), you should make it such that all of them enable smooth scrolling.

Think about it, what is the **[main purpose](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html)** of your anchor tags? It refers to a document address. The user mainly experiences:

1. Redirect to a new site.
2. Navigate through the current site.
3. Download request of a file.

Therefore, as long as your smooth scroll behavior is specific to all anchors; then you do not need to account for specific anchor behavior. Why? Because you do not care if the anchor redirects/download, smooth scroll should not trigger since the page does not move at all.

**TLDR**:

Try changing your JQuery selector from:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() { //...
```

To:

```
$('a').click(function() { //...
```

Do some unit testing for all scenarios. If that does not solve your problem, then we need to identify what other JavaScript is affecting your smooth scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the kudos for ideas :). 

I managed to change the selector so it affects all the anchor links not just the internal ones yet it didn't solve the problem. I've tried to test it with another menu section yet the result is the same. It's jumping to "Projects" section instead of smoothly scrolling. I also added instrumental button with anchor link to "Projects" section to see if it's a problem with scrolling script but it worked like a charm. Seems to me like it's a problem with menu script (**scrolling.js**) rather then with **scroll.js**

Comment: @pawcza that would make sense since you are not deviating from what scrolling.js is trying to do. Answer your own question for validity at the very least

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer and the kudos for ideas :). I managed to change the selector so it affects all the anchor links not just the internal ones yet it didn't solve the problem. I've tried to test it with another menu section yet the result is the same. It's jumping to "Projects" section instead of smoothly scrolling. I also added instrumental button with anchor link to "Projects" section to see if it's a problem with scrolling script but it worked like a charm. Seems to me like it's a problem with menu script (**scrolling.js**) rather then with **scroll.js**

**EDIT:** The **scrolling.js** is deleting anchor links when the menu reaches 20% of section height then it rewrites them as menu goes vertical version. Is it possible that the **scroll.js** script is losing the focus on links as it doesn't scan the document all the time? And so is it possible to make the script rescan the document?

**EDIT2:** I've managed to fix it by removing the **.html()** function from **scrolling.js**